# Powershell comand not working but no error

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a powershell script that looks for a folder then creates the folder is it does not exist then extracts a .zip file to that folder. everything is working except this 1 line

```
Expand-Archive -LiteralPath '\\server\share\subfolder\archive.zip' -DestinationPath C:\local_folder -Force
```

When I run this line alone I get no error but it does not write to the folder

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Did you try copying the zip off the file share first? With slow shares, its often faster that way too.

Comment: Tried that with the same result

Comment: Can you run it with the `-Verbose` parameter?

Comment: How was the Archive.zip file created?  Not all zip files are the same and `Expand-Archive` may not know how to read Archive.zip.

Answer (score 2):

Thank You Using -Verbose gave me the answer. The archive was empty. I used Windows to create the archive so it wasn't 3rd party software issue. I recreated the archive and everything works Thank You again